# How to remove tooltip of map chart on click event?

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts

So, I am using fusion charts to display India map and further on click event, I am plotting new chart i.e of that state. But, the tooltip of India map is not being removed.

Following are the code and screenshot:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/61l014j2mz

(Click on bihar state)

Screenshot:
[image: Normal India map showing states and tooltip]

[image: state map but showing tooltip of india map]

Comment: Sorry about my wrong answer. Are you working with this code only in Code Sandbox? Or is this happening also on your local development environment? Because Code Sandbox seemed to be under really heavy load rendering those maps. It behaved really strangely in a way that I couldn't even go through your source files. It could be some kind of bug related to the Sandbox environment.

Comment: No, actually, working on the local environment, just modified it for code sandbox. But, working is the same. the bug is in code probably. Also, thought of destroying the map on click event.

Comment: this is a problem with the current version of FusionCharts, maybe they will fix in the next version

Answer (score 0):

You can use  "showToolTip": "0"

```
"charts":{
   "showToolTip": "0"
}
```

To know more about it please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/map-guide/simple-data-driven-maps

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var salesMap = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'maps/world',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '600',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Global Population",
        "subCaption": "6.3 Billion",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "formatNumberScale": "0",
        "numberSuffix": "M",
        "showLabels": "1",
        "showToolTip": "0"
      },
      "colorrange": {
        "color": [{
          "minvalue": "0",
          "maxvalue": "100",
          "code": "#D0DFA3",
          "displayValue": "< 100M"
        }, {
          "minvalue": "100",
          "maxvalue": "500",
          "code": "#B0BF92",
          "displayValue": "100-500M"
        }, {
          "minvalue": "500",
          "maxvalue": "1000",
          "code": "#91AF64",
          "displayValue": "500M-1B"
        }, {
          "minvalue": "1000",
          "maxvalue": "5000",
          "code": "#A9FF8D",
          "displayValue": "> 1B"
        }]
      },
      "data": [{
        "id": "NA",
        "value": "515"
      }, {
        "id": "SA",
        "value": "373"
      }, {
        "id": "AS",
        "value": "3875"
      }, {
        "id": "EU",
        "value": "727"
      }, {
        "id": "AF",
        "value": "885"
      }, {
        "id": "AU",
        "value": "32"
      }],

    },
    "events": {
     "entityClick": function(evt, data) {
        alert("You have clicked on " + data.label + ".");
      },
    }
  }).render();
});
```

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v24fo1wb/